# Can't access local files in data/data of some phones

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, adb

I'm having three not rooted phones here. Two of them have Android 10 and one has Android 8.0. On one with Android 10 I just cant access the app files in /data/data directory with the Device File Explorer in Android Studio.
The error I get is:

`run-as: /data has wrong owner: 0/1000, not 1000´

I'm just not finding anything useful to fix this.

Comment: I consider that by adding code which you are using you will greatly increase the chances of getting helpfull answer or advice)

Comment: @DanilasaysReinstateMonica I'm sorry, I edited the question. It is not really about the code, since I can access the app files via the Device File Explorer in Android Studio right after running the app on multiple devices and also the emulator, without doing having the app to do anything except displaying some buttons. There might be some adb commands or settings in Android Studio or the phone itself I don't know about.

Comment: everything that can be said by info u put here is only that the way u trying to access data is wrong. Some info: Linux starts creating "normal" users at UID 1000. So a user with UID 1000 is probably the first user ever created on that particular system (beside root, who always has UID 0), and android as u know Linux-based OS. I beleive this is not smth that will solve ur problem, but I also beleive that if u will not edit ur question with more information u won't get really usefull answer

Comment: @wileykay311 Did you ever solve this?

Comment: According to my experience, it's the abnormal status on the Android device side causes this problem, and a reboot should reset the status and make everything work again. Don't know the exact cause though, and no guarantees it won't happen again. There may exist a more convenient solution, like restart the device side of adb server module? I haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had to dive into the comments of the original question to solve it for myself, I'll repeat the answer that helped me.

I uninstalled the app, restarted my phone, installed it again with android studio and it worked like a charm after that.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still looking for an answer.

This most likely happens when your database is created in the past (probably from some code that was a bit off). I advise you to delete the existing database from the device file explorer, make sure your code is right, and re-run the app.

This should create a new database and work.

Comment: Im not looking for an answer anymore, because I had this problem on just on device. What database do you mean? I couldnt even the directory of the app in the device file explorer. Even after deleting the app and installing again.